# Locale keeps resetting between switching pages. Nuxt-i18n

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I am trying to set up localization for my Nuxt frontend. Every time I switch to English and then move to an other subpage of my website it does reset back to German.

This is my LanguageSelector

```
<template>
  <div class="lang-dropdown">
    <select v-model="$i18n.locale">
      <option
        v-for="lang in $i18n.locales"
        :key="lang.code"
        :value="lang.code"
        onchange="changeLocale"
      >
        {{ lang.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>
```

This is my i18n config file

```
import de from '../locales/de.json'
import en from '../locales/en.json'

export default {
  local: 'en',
  fallbackLocale: 'de',
  messages: { de, en },
  strategy: 'prefix'
}
```

This is my buildModules section of the Nuxt.config.js

```
 ['nuxt-i18n',
      {
        defaultLocale: 'de',
        seo: true,
        locales: [
          {
            code: 'de',
            name: 'Deutsch',
            iso: 'de-DE'
          },
          {
            code: 'en',
            name: 'English',
            iso: 'en-US'
          }
        ],
        vueI18n: i18n
      }]
```

Answer (score 3):

according to this quote from nuxtjs/i18n docs

> When using detectBrowserLanguage and wanting to persist locale on a route change, you must call one of the functions that update the stored locale cookie. Call either setLocaleCookie(locale) to persist just the cookie locale or setLocale(locale) to both persist the cookie locale and switch the route to the specified locale. Otherwise, locale might switch back to the saved one during navigation.

https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/lang-switcher

you should use `$i18n.setLocale` instead of changing the property `locale` 
using `setLocale` will change the cookie that stores the chosen locale

in your case this code should work

```
<template>
  <div class="lang-dropdown">
    <select @change="(e) => $i18n.setLocale(e.target.value)">
      <option
        v-for="lang in $i18n.locales"
        :key="lang.code"
        :value="lang.code"
        onchange="changeLocale"
      >
        {{ lang.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Al-bimani's answer is what it says in documentation. However it didn't work for me. So I realized my mistake. I had a nuxt-link like this for example:

```html
<nuxt-link to="/about"> // instead of this I started using this;
<nuxt-link :to="localePath('/about')">
```

Before **localePath** it was resetting the locale after navigation. After adding **localePath** in nuxt-link it simply navigates with the locale you change.

Answer (score -1):

Set in your nuxt config:

```
i18n: {
    ...
    strategy: 'no_prefix',
    ...
}
```

to prevent the switch when always working with the same URLs (so not with /en/foo and /de/foo but just /foo) to keep the locale between nuxt-links which you somewhere set by `this.$i18n.setLocale('en');` before.